# Using css selector, how to grab nth child of of element using it's class

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, webdriver

After getting the number of elements with a specific class, how do I iterate through them?

I am using webdriver to automate some tests. I can grab the number of elements with a specific class using

```
<div>
    <tr class="test"></tr>
    <tr class="test"></tr>
    <tr class="test"></tr>
    <tr class="test"></tr>
</div>
```

```
let trNum = (await client.elements("div > tr.test")).value.length;
```

trNum will equal 4 in this case. I want to iterate through each of the elements, preferably using nth-child. How can I do this?
I've tried

```
"div > tr.test:nth-child(1)"
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Please check your html. The `<tr>` is for inside `<table>` elements only. Changing `<tr>` in `<div>` will be better to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` to select the unknown amount of .test classes. After that, loop throught this list with `querySelector` because you know for sure the item exists.

```
<div>
  <div class="test">item 1</div>
  <div class="test">item 2</div>
  <div class="test">item 3</div>
  <div class="test">item 4</div>
</div>

<script>
// nodelist (in example node 0 - 3)
let divs = document.querySelectorAll(".test");
// How many nodes (in example 4)
let divCount = divs.length;
// loop through nth-child(1) - nth-child(4) <=== not 0 - 3
var i, selector, divItem;
for (i = 1; i <= divCount; i++) {
  selector = ".test:nth-child(" + i + ")";
  divItem = document.querySelector(selector);
  console.log(divItem.innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

For explanation I did not put lines together.

Comment: Variable `divs` is an array and can be referenced as such.  Thus, you do not need to use `querySelector` to select each item, just `divs[i]`. Also, using `children` of the parent node would be more precise selection rather than all class=test divisions. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children.  So, select the parent desired, and then all of it's children elements as a set.

Comment: I'm aware of the array but the question was to reference each div with `nth-child(n)` to find a certain div in this array. That's why `querySelector()`  is used. Using children of the parent node is normally better but in this case the parent is a div.